# What is the regular expression for The set of all strings of a's, b's, and c's that contain at least two a's

Tags: finite-automata

What is the regular expression for  The set of all strings of a's, b's, and c's that contain at least two a's.can anybody help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck with your attempts? For this type of problem, you can often start with just the character you're concerned with (in this case `a`) and, and fill in the other characters as necessary. The regular expression `aa` matches two `a`s. Can you fill in the rest from that starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See try to break it into simple language. All we want is atleast 2 a's doesn't matter where their position is and there is not condition on count and position of b and c. So it should go like

> (a+b+c)* .a. (a+b+c)* .a. (a+b+c)*

Any combination of a,b,c followed by a followed by again any combination of a,b,c followed by a which fullfils our condition then any combination of a,b,c.

Answer (score 0):

We have to write the regular expression for the set of all strings that contain
a's,b's and c's.The condition is that there should be atleast two a's in any of the string that is produced by the regular expression but there is no condition for the number of b's and c's and their position. So,
(a+b+c)* .a.(a+b+c)* .a.(a+b+c)*
regular expression satisfies the given condition.
The above regular expression produces the required set of strings which definitely has 2 a's and their position doesn't matter.